# MODULE : AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, jupyter-lab

I cant understand what's wrong. I'm using jupyterlab to make a CNN model for school but I get this error when running my code which idk wat its is. When I search online the solutions don't make sense to me.

I reinstalled my conda prompt and made new environment for my code but its still the same.

Comment: You must make your question clear with source code, screenshot, error message. What is *idk wat its is*?

Comment: urm how do i display code it says its too long

Comment: You could show the code that emits the error.   ... and the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0):

make virtual environment and then install the tensorflow ! I hope its Work.